# Formatting trouble when printing to terminal

Tags: java, terminal

public class Banner {

```
// Main method
public static void main(String [] args) {

    // Prints out CSC220
    System.out.println(" *******   ***********   ***********    **********      ****");
    System.out.println("***        **                      **            **    *    *");
    System.out.println("***        **                     **            **    *      *");
    System.out.println("**         **********           **            **     *        *");
    System.out.println("**                 **         **            **       *        *");
    System.out.println("**                 **       **            **          *      *");
    System.out.println("****               **     ***           ***            *    *");
    System.out.println(" ********  **********    ***********   ***********      ****");


}
```

}

When I run it on terminal, it looks like this:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwJHx.png)

Comment: Don't mix tabs and spaces (just use *spaces*).

Comment: Thanks! Worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is that you may be mixing tabs and spaces in the text you are printing.

Comment: No I didn't copy Elliott's answer.  I looked twice at the attached picture which took time.  I even up-voted his comment :)  If you don't know someone, give them the benefit of the doubt.